# ¿Cómo hago salto de linea dentro de un JComboBox?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy tratando de poner un texto largo dentro de un JComboBox, por lo que necesito hacer saltos de lineas. Si hago un \n dentro del string no hace nada puesto que es el combobox el que debe permitir un salto de linea.

```
respuesta3.add(new Opcion("administración de O2 por halo, máscara, cámara, naricera alto flujo o incubadora \n y/o VMNI intermitente "));
```

Ese es el código de una de las opciones que va dentro del jcombobox (el objeto opción es un string solamente).

```
 e3 = new JLabel("• Cuidados de Oxigenoterapia");
      panel1.add(e3);     
      c3 = new JComboBox();
      action3 evento3 = new action3();
      c3.addActionListener(evento3);
      panel1.add(c3);
```

Aquí arriba instancio mi jcombobox y lo agrego al panel

```
for (Opcion o3 : res.respuesta3()){
            c3.addItem(o3);
        }
```

Aquí es cuando le agrego los items del arraylist respuesta3 al combobox

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar HTML en algunos componenentes swing de java.
De hecho lo puedes usar en JComboBox.

Trata con este código:

```
respuesta3.add(new Opcion("<HTML>administración de O2 por halo, máscara, cámara, naricera alto flujo o incubadora<br> y/o VMNI intermitente</HTML>"));
```

De esta forma puedes brincar renglones y usar mas funciones de HTML para, colores, tamaños, etc..., en tu JComboBox.

Anexo liga de tutorial de componentes java, viene lo de HTML...

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html

Suerte.

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que editar la celda seleccionable  para que te muestre el salto de línea donde lo queres. No estoy seguro si funciona en swing, no lo probe, pero en javafx si. Espero que te sirva, a mi me funciono de esta manera:

```
cmbItem.setButtonCell(new ListCell< Ajo >(){

 //clase es Ajo,comboBox es cbmItem

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Ajo item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setDisable(false);
            } else {
                setText(item.getTipo()+"\nhola"); //este es un ejemplo de salto de linea

            }
        }

    });
```

[image: muestra esto:]